# Asymptotic notations and inequalities

Tags: inequality, asymptotics

Suppose that we have two implicit functions

$$f(t)=\log\frac{t}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{t}\right),\,
g(t)=\log t+O\left(\frac{1}{t}\right).$$

Let $z(t)$ be a function such that $f(t)< z(t) < g(t)$, when $t$ is sufficiently large.

Can the last inequalities be replaced by any known asymptotic notations?

A bit more general version of my question could be "Let $g(t)-f(t)=constant+o(1)$ and $f(t)< z(t) < g(t)$, as $t\to\infty$. Can the last inequalities be expressed by any known asymptotic notations?"

The idea of my question is that the constants implied by $O$ might be different and it is confusing to write $\log\frac{t}{2}+O\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)<z(t)<\log t+O\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$ or $\log\frac{t}{2}<z(t)+O\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)<\log t$, as $t \to \infty$.

Comment: The closest I can think of is [big](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-theta-notation) [theta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann–Landau_notations). It is not exactly what you want but for $f=\mathcal O(g)$ you can work with it

Comment: From the inequalities $f < z < g$ you can deduce that $z(t) = \log t + O(1)$, but that isn't equivalent to the inequalities.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I don't see how you can deduce $O(1)$ there.

Comment: There exist constants $A, B, T > 0$ such that $$f(t) > \log \frac{t}{2} - A = \log t - \log 2 - A,$$ $$g(t) < \log t + B,$$ and $f(t) < z(t) < g(t)$ for all $t > T$. Thus $$\log t - \log 2 - A < z(t) < \log t + B$$ and hence $$-\log 2 - A < z(t) - \log t < B$$ for all $t > T$, which implies that $z(t) = \log t + O(1)$. @user58697

Comment: You should write $\Omega(\frac{1}{t})$ on the LHS, and this also solves the problem of confusing the two implied constants.